# MVC3 Doesn't accept cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, session-cookies

I just launched my first MVC3 application and everything works fine except cookies authorisation. When a user visits my site and logs in I set a .ASPAUTH cookie with data about that user. It works well untill some time passes. Then I have to log in again even though the cookie is in the browser and I can see that expiration is set to one year later. It works fine on my localhost.
It seems to me that it instead of setting my info into cookie it is somehow in session, but even if I restart my computer within an hour I am still logged in. But if I don't visit the web in 1 hour, after that I am logged out.

Thanks for any help.

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                1,
                requestedUser.Name,
                DateTime.Now,
                DateTime.Now.AddYears(1),
                true,
                string.Format("{0};{1};{2}", requestedUser.IDUser.ToString(), requestedUser.IsAdmin.ToString(), profilePicture));

            string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
            cookie.Expires = keepLogged == "keepLogged" ? DateTime.Now.AddYears(1) : DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);

            this.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Posts");
```

Comment: An app pool restart probably due to idle timeout is invalidating the session cookies - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277944/is-it-possible-to-recycle-iis-application-pools-without-losing-user-sessions

Comment: can you show the code where you're setting your forms authentication?

Comment: @tawman Thanks for help, but I can see the cookie on client's browser, why the application cannot? Sorry for lame question, but I really have to solve this and don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: @PetrMares The client-side cookie is only as a valid as the server-side's recollection of it existing. Once the app pool recycles, the server-side session management has no memory of the token provided by the client-side cookie. You can use a database to persist the session-cookies on the server-side to get around this issue.

Comment: @tawman: I will check, what are my options. I hope there is another way, in case I have to do this, can you show me some example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the machinekey in web.config something like this

```
 <machineKey validationKey="4B79DF965DC586D2B267BDECB4580D40EE6811EE171AC65D929BECD8865C09ED8681B92F2177FE9F72B8E822B26914C79C1FF590CCEE65469CBC6FACD7D9F203" decryptionKey="CF39BCCD33BC38D17A704DFEB85AD9C5F265669FCD6AB54C" validation="SHA1" />
```

You can use this http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey tool to do it, but you have to paste it intro web.config.

Everytime the app pool recycels the app is restarted and if it's not set in web.config, a new machinekey is automatically generated. The FormsAuthentication cookie is hashed with that machine key and every time it changes, the cookie becomes invalid

Comment: This seems like a solution I was looking for, I will try it.