# What is the limit of data that can be stored in the In-Proc mode in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

There are multiple modes in which session data can be stored in a ASP.net C# application. One of them is InProc mode. What is the limit of the maximum amount of data that can be held in the InProc mode? Is this a configurable limit?

Edit: I know this is probably un-cool and even sounds blasphemous but I am in a unique situation where I will probably need to store 10MB files in the session. Probably dozens of them at a time. Thus the question.

Comment: As much unused memory as there is?

Comment: If you have to ask, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Word of caution - be wary about storing enormous quantities of data in a user's session. It's fine if your using InProc, but if you move to using a state-server (e.g. because you want to use load-balancing), you'll suddenly find you are transferring megabytes of data per request, which can be a massive performance hit.

Comment: Is session the only alternative? Is caching (either System.Runtime, nhibernate, or the like) not available to you?

Comment: No, there should be no datastore at all.

Comment: I ask, because you are using Session as a datastore already. It is not really meant for what you are doing, you should be using a tool that does the function you are looking for.

Comment: And when I said nhibernate, I meant memcached.

Comment: I mean. What is needed is a datastore that does not have an API through which it's contents can be accessed outside the ASP.net application.

Comment: Tim Medora's MemoryCache option seems to be the most appropriate then.

Comment: _"I mean. What is needed is a datastore that does not have an API through which it's contents can be accessed outside the ASP.net application."_ - then focus on that. Using the correct permissions, you can set up a directory, database or cache that only your application can access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not this is a good question or a scary one depends on whether or not you are trying to plan capacity for numerous "skinny" sessions (fine) or planning to put a huge amount of data into session (bad).

IIS allows private memory control and virtual memory control. This is unlimited by default; if you do set a limit, it can be used to trigger app pool recycles. Recycling the app pool is probably not desirable, e.g. 1000 users are logged in, memory limit is reached, site restarts and [session data is lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277944/is-it-possible-to-recycle-iis-application-pools-without-losing-user-sessions) for everyone. Request throttling might be more appropriate.

Remember, "The amount of data storage reserved for a process is only limited by the amount of space that the operating system can get on the disk." ([reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx)) but as soon as you are paging to disk, performance will suffer badly. @RB's comment about out of process "fat" sessions causing heavy network traffic is also apropos.

As a note, [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) provides more granular size/expiration control. It's [very similar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd985642) to what ASP.Net uses. Based on your comment about 10MB files, I would suggest looking at this option. It will run in process like session (and still be subject to the same memory limit as session), but you can [control it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.trim.aspx) to some degree.

Answer (score 0):

There is a memory limit you can configure for each Application Pool in IIS7. But I'm not sure whether you can configure Session State memory in detail.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit on the length or size of data in session, as far as the server or host machine has memory available with it.