# my website's first request takes long time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, iis

http://chatempire.org/

I developed this website

This website is powered by **.NET MVC C#, LINQ.**

When i enter my website first time, it takes long time about **15 seconds**.

When you are connected the website if you refresh it, it is fast to refresh, no problem again. But i close the website and a few minutes later, i enter the website it takes long time again about 15s.

I have tested the performance of website. https://gtmetrix.com/reports/chatempire.org/Br6mXRTp

I can not understand the problem.

I have sent a ticket to my hosting server owner and have asked to you.

I need help, thanks.

Comment: IIS automatically shuts down your process if it's been idle for a certain amount of time. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985710/iis-idle-timeout-vs-recycle)

Comment: i will check the link completely later, i have to sleep now. but not wasted for 20 minutes to turn iis off. just 2-3mins is enough to be waited 15secs again.

Comment: It also depends on your size of scripts,css,images, for the first time loading of a page, Try to do client side caching..it may help you