# .netcore reset registered singleton services after idle

Tags: c#, .net, iis, .net-core

I registered a singleton service, but it got reset if the web application goes idle(no visitor after a period of time). Where should i set the idle time/life time of .netcore application? Or was it recycle by IIS?

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985710/iis-idle-timeout-vs-recycle).

Comment: thanks for answering, yes i guess i should set the idle timeout in process model! was looking at the recycle timeout and got confused

Comment: You are not supposed to change those IIS settings, but review your application design. Anything that does not work with IIS model (such as recycle/idle shutdown) should be revised (like moving to a Windows service).