# IIS shutsdown website even though timeout for app pool is set to 0

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

Title pretty much says it all. I have created a simple ASP.NET core 3.1 website which runs a MQTT subscriper. My problem is that after a while I see message in event viewer:

`Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/MYWEBSITE' has shutdown.`

[image]

Is there something I should add in the website itself or in IIS to make the website always running?

Comment: Does the website take too long to start up again once it has shut down?

Comment: Oh, and [user nPcomp points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42820639/1115360) that "IIS now has `Idle Time-out Action : Suspend` setting."

Comment: Try changing your Idle Time-out to a bigger number instead of a smaller number

Comment: website starts quite rapidly. I would not like to suspend the site at all but keep it running always.

Time-out is set to 0 since that should make it disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a complete step to step guide how to fix this from:
https://www.taithienbo.com/how-to-auto-start-and-keep-an-asp-net-core-web-application-and-keep-it-running-on-iis/

The missing part from my config was to add application initialization to server roles.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem before and solved with set Rapid-Fail protection to false.
If you trust to your server performance
or increase failure and maximum failures count.