# HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start on working web site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

web site works normally, but about once a day it throws error and stopped working with error `HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start`, event log says Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite.com\Plugins\bin\Plugin.plugin.dll' is denied. But there is access to that path. I tried to remove plugin, but same error happens on different plugin folder.

I tried different solutions from stackoverflow, but still no success.

It starts to work when recycle a pool, I have set up it recycling for once a day, but it happens not as recycling pool schedule time.

Apprecite any help.

Comment: You can refer this post https://dotnetblog.asphostportal.com/how-to-fix-error-500-30-asp-net-core-app-failed-to-start/. Make sure you have installed correct Asp.net core bundle version.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution here: [IIS shutsdown website even though timeout for app pool is set to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64341217/iis-shutsdown-website-even-though-timeout-for-app-pool-is-set-to-0)

and here: https://www.taithienbo.com/how-to-auto-start-and-keep-an-asp-net-core-web-application-and-keep-it-running-on-iis/