# NET Core 3.1 Worker Service in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, service, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm developing a worker service and would like to know if there is any way to publish in iis. Or if you can make an api using hosted services not be shut down due to inactivity

Comment: Why do you use worker service? Do you want your web application to be always on?

Comment: Yes. I need it to be always active

Comment: Console app  or webapp ？

Comment: is a web api with hosted services

Answer (score 1):

You can set `Always on` in IIS.

[image]

[image]

## Reason

[The value of Idle Time-out value is 20 minutes.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85/idle-worker-process-page-out-in-iis85#configure-idle-worker-process-page-out-for-a-single-application-pool)

That's why your webapi will slowly when you access it sometimes.

> [Idle Timeout is if no action has been asked from your web app, it the process will drop and release everything from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985710/iis-idle-timeout-vs-recycle)