# How does an application pool recycle affect ASP Net Session State?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I know when application pool is recycled a new worker process is initiated but I am confused with how expired and valid sessions are treated in this process? which passes to new worker process thread to and which are eliminated? what it will do with:

- User A's session has expired
- User B's session is valid

after recycling, when User A and User B will request then what will be their session statet?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have a single web server, and you've used the default `InProc` mode for SessionState persistence, then any data that you've added to the session's Dictionary in your server code will be lost during an App Pool recycle - after the recycle, when your code next accesses an entry in the `SessionState` dictionary, it will return `null`.

This will similarly happen if you have multiple web servers across a load balancer, with session state incorrectly configured as `InProc`, and the user returns to a different server (i.e. without sticky routing).

(The Session State cookie stored on the browser may still be valid for several minutes yet).

The way to allow Session State to 'survive' an App Pool recycle, server crash, or to span across a farm of servers is to persist data stored in `SessionState`, so that the server (or servers) can again retrieve the data when the user's session returns. Easiest is to use one of the [out of the box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) solutions, viz a separate `StateServer` process, or store state in a `SqlServer` database. Custom persistence is also an option.

One caveat - note that any data that you store in an 'out of process' mode such as `StateServer` or `SqlServer` needs to be serializable - this can be a breaking change when you switch out of `InProc`.

Comment: The cookie will still be available, but any data you've stored in the server `SessionState` will be gone with InProc as the worker process recycles. e.g. Try adding `SessionState["SomeKey"] = "BeforeReboot";`, then recycling, and reading  it again.  [Another Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4278040/314291)

Comment: I tried this too. Session["someKey"] is still persist after recycled. :( thank you so much for your efforts and still I am looking forward from you and others to diagnose and help me.

Comment: StuartLC they fact you just illustrated are proven true. thanks buddy